# flutter: how to create/write a file to a specific directory path

Tags: flutter, file, directory

i'm trying to create/write a file to a specific directory. i already have my code but the problem is i always got an error saying:

```
flutter: FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AF14244D-E8C4-4B9A-8005-D7CA7CC3520B/Documents/cache/files/abcb-1234567890' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)
```

here's my code:

```
Directory directory = Platform.isAndroid ? await getExternalStorageDirectory() : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    
String path = directory.path + '/cache/files';
File file = new File('$path/$fileID');
final results = await post(...);
file.writeAsBytesSync(results);
```

what am i missing?

additional question: if anyone would know how can i access created date of the file that i have just created? - reason for this is to delete them after a set date or like an expiry date.

appreciate any help. thank you in advance. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure this path exists?
I belive your code is executing part `getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()`
That mean you are not on android.
Can you access this path using other app (some file explorer etc)?

The interesting part is here:
`'/cache/files'` maybe this folder doesn't exist.

Here is on my Windows:

```
var dir = io.Directory.fromUri(Uri.directory('UNO\\DUE\\'));
dir.createSync(recursive: true);

var file = io.File('${dir.absolute.path}\demo.txt');
file.writeAsStringSync('ABCDEFHJ');
```

Without `dir.createSync(recursive: true)`; without recursive parameter I have exactly same problem.

Comment: yeah. i think that's what am missing. thank you. i added this 'await directory.create(recursive: true);'